# Recover data from a database from a custom link

Tags: php, html

I am currently developing a website managing my movies, these are registered in a database and display in a table in html and php. Each title in the table contains a custom link like this:`echo "<td><a target='Main_Frame' href='movie.php?Aname=" . $row['titre'] ."'>". $row['titre'] . "</a>"`
I would like the movie.php page to display the information of the selected movie.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Please make sure that in your table `movie_id` is available..

```
echo "<td><a href='movie.php?id=" . $row['ids'] ."'>". $row['titre'] . "</a>";
```

**movie.php**

```
$id=$_GET["id"];

$qry="select * from movie where movie_id=".$id;
$result = mysql_query($qry);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  // here is your move information
  print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this is not secure. You should never just accept  raw $_GET data and query a database with it. You should at the very least be using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are saving a movie_id in your movie table, so just add the movie_id to the custom link.

Movie.php
Here you can get the movie_id that was passed and retrieve the corresponding movie details from the database.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need Id.
**For example:**

```
echo "<td><a target='Main_Frame' href='movie.php?Aname=" . $row['ids'] ."'>". $row['titre'] . "</a>"
```

Do the following code in movie.php page.

```
$id=$_GET["ids"];

$qry="select * from movie where movie_id=".$id;
$result = mysql_query($qry);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  // here is your move information
  print_r($row);
}
```

I hope its helpful to you..

Comment: Not working :( here is my code :<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","movie");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$id=$_GET["id"];

$qry="SELECT * FROM allmovie WHERE id='" . $id . "'";
$result = mysql_query($qry, $con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
  // here is your move information
  print_r($row);
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>